# Image zoom/magnify using javascript plugin, in django framework

Tags: javascript, html, django, model, magnify

I have a hard time incorporating a magnifying javascript plugin feature.

Basically, I was able to run this plugin on a static html template with static images. but I can't seem to run it at all on my django built website.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Items</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1" />

        <title>EasyZoom, jQuery image zoom plugin</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pygments.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/easyzoom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>


        {%if entry.image_set.get.imgfile%}
  <!-- images are extracted from the entry model --> 
        <div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay">
            <a href="{{MEDIA_URL}} {{entry.image_set.get.imgfile.url}}">
                <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}} {{entry.image_set.get.imgfile.url}}" alt="Green-SLI" />
            </a>
        </div>
        {%endif%}



        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/easyzoom.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Instantiate EasyZoom instances
            var $easyzoom = $('.easyzoom').easyZoom();

            // Setup thumbnails example
            var api1 = $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--with-thumbnails').data('easyZoom');

            $('.thumbnails').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
                var $this = $(this);

                e.preventDefault();

                // Use EasyZoom's `swap` method
                api1.swap($this.data('standard'), $this.attr('href'));
            });

            // Setup toggles example
            var api2 = $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--with-toggle').data('easyZoom');

            $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
                var $this = $(this);

                if ($this.data("active") === true) {
                    $this.text("Switch on").data("active", false);
                    api2.teardown();
                } else {
                    $this.text("Switch off").data("active", true);
                    api2._init();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>



    </html>
```

My images are located inside entry model, and they are extracted from there. Does that have an impact on whether the magnify script will work or not? Since they are not exactly static.

Also, I have multiple css files, not sure if that impacts anything. I disabled the main css in the base template to see if it was interfering, but still nothing.

Is there a more efficient way that I incorporate a magnifying function? I have no experience really with javascript.

**Here is the modified code that actually works.**

```
> {% load staticfiles %}
> 
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>     <title>Items</title>    <meta
> charset="utf-8" />    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
> content="IE=Edge;chrome=1" />
> 
>   <title>EasyZoom, jQuery image zoom plugin</title>
> 
>               <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href={% static "css/easyzoom.css" %} /> </head> <body>     {%if
> entry.image_set.get.imgfile%}
> 
> 
>   <div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay">
>       <a href="{{MEDIA_URL}} {{entry.image_set.get.imgfile.url}}">
>           <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}} {{entry.image_set.get.imgfile.url}}" alt="Green-SLI" width = '240' height ='180' />
>       </a>    </div>  {%endif%}
> 
> 
> 
>   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "css/easyzoom.js"
> %}"></script>     <script>        // Instantiate EasyZoom instances       var
> $easyzoom = $('.easyzoom').easyZoom();
> 
>       // Setup thumbnails example         var api1 =
> $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--with-thumbnails').data('easyZoom');
> 
>       $('.thumbnails').on('click', 'a', function(e) {             var $this =
> $(this);
> 
>           e.preventDefault();
> 
>           // Use EasyZoom's `swap` method
>           api1.swap($this.data('standard'), $this.attr('href'));      });
> 
>       // Setup toggles example        var api2 =
> $easyzoom.filter('.easyzoom--with-toggle').data('easyZoom');
> 
>       $('.toggle').on('click', function() {           var $this = $(this);
> 
>           if ($this.data("active") === true) {
>               $this.text("Switch on").data("active", false);
>               api2.teardown();            } else {
>               $this.text("Switch off").data("active", true);
>               api2._init();           }       });     </script> </body>
> 
> 
> 
> </html>
```

Comment: Do you have any console traceback?

Comment: I don't know what that means, but I solved the problem by incorporating the '{% load staticfiles %}  in the template. I also modified the .css and .js files accordingly. Please have a look at the modified reference code.